# how to disabled angular material menu if modal is opened

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular11

I use angular material menu, for header menu.
It is nested menu and open on hover.  There is a link of code.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-nested-menu-yclrmd?embed=1&file=app/nested-menu-example.html
when I open  angular material  dialog component  header is also  active and I  can  on hover  and  route to other component.  I know this is the fault of the z-index. But if  z-index  will not  be 1050,  then menu does not work on hover and mat-menus open and close.

Comment: Please post a full example for your problem next time

Comment: Why you don't open the mat-dialog with the option `hasBackdrop=true`, to prevent clicking anywhere outside the dialog while it is opened? This will work for the `mat-menu` or any other navigate button on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the z-index of the overlaycontainer in your styles.css

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1050;
}
```

Comment: I try this and  it works  when  dialog is open but  when  dialog is closed  mat-menu opened and close quickly. it doesn't work.

Comment: close the menues before opening the dialog without using a timeout